# Dynamic EditText and CheckBox and some data in each row of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, baseadapter, android-listfragment

I have a dynamic listview and in each row of it I have a dynamic EditText and a dynamic CheckBox and some data from database. The code below illustrates part of it.

I didn't find a way to set (fill) appropriately both EditText and CheckBox. This listview is in a fragmentlist. When I click a button in another fragment on the same screen, I want to capture the information in each row of the listview.

Could you give me some tip to customize my code below and fill apropriately EditText and CheckBox according my wish?

One problem that is happening is that when I fill the first EditText in the first row of the listview the last EditText in the last row of the listview is being filled. I don't know why it's happening.

```
class PedidoAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<ProdutoDTO> productDetails = new ArrayList<>();
private int count;
private Context context;
private EditText editTextValorDoProduto;
private CheckBox checkBoxCompraRecorrente;

public PedidoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProdutoDTO> product_details)
{
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.productDetails = product_details;
    this.count = product_details.size();
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return productDetails.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;

    ProdutoDTO tempProduto = productDetails.get(position);

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pedido, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.product_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        holder.principioativo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.principioativo);
        holder.valorDoProduto = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.product_name.setText(tempProduto.getProduto());

    holder.principioativo.setText(tempProduto.getPrincipioativo());

    holder.valorDoProduto.setText(tempProduto.getValor().toString());

    holder.checkBox.setChecked(tempProduto.isVendaRecorrente());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView product_name;
    TextView principioativo;
    EditText valorDoProduto;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    //Button addToCart;
}
}
```

I have the code below from where I fill a part of each listview row. Each row has an EditText and a Checkbox which have to be filled by the user.

```
 public List<ItemPendenteDTO> getItemPendenteList(String url)
    {
        ItemPendenteDTO itemPendenteDTO;
        JSONArray itemPendenteList;
        try
        {
            String stringJson = JSONParser.getJSONFromAPI(url);
            itemPendenteList = new JSONArray(stringJson);

            for(int i=0; i < itemPendenteList.length(); i++)
            {
                itemPendenteDTO = new ItemPendenteDTO();
                JSONObject obj = itemPendenteList.getJSONObject(i);

                itemPendenteDTO.setIdItemPendente(obj.getInt("idItemPendente"));
                itemPendenteDTO.setIdPedidoPendente(obj.getLong("idPedidoPendente"));
                itemPendenteDTO.setIdProduto(obj.getLong("idProduto"));

                itensPendentesDTO.add(itemPendenteDTO);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return itensPendentesDTO;
    }
```

Also, I have a the tag below in an xml file where I insert value for each EditText in each row.

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/principioativo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtValorDoProduto"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtValorDoProduto"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:background="#71cad2"
    android:hint="Valor"/>
```

The code for the checkbox that is in each listview row is below.

```
 <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Aceito venda programada"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />
```

Comment: where you store value in editText in your `ProdutoDTO` object ?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I added more code. Maybe the solution for your question is the solution for my problem. Also, maybe it's missing more implementation for my code. Check it please.